# How to assign roles to users in firebase (android app)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, authentication

How to give roles to user in firebase for my android app??
I want to differentiate employee and manager login.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you have to add a role node in the firebase database saving  the user's unique id like uid seprated by it their role.

```
"role" : {
"uid_1" : "emp",
"uid_2" : "manger" }
```